# Seal script translation

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

[image][image][image][image]enter image description hereI have two bronze seals in the form of tigers which I think may be Korean , the first with characters in what I think is Chinese small seal script the second in a normal type os script; Could any one help with reading the characters please. I attach photos:
Thanking you in advance
Philip[image]

Comment: Do you mind uploading the second seal? It may provide enough context to decipher this seal. I suspect it says 詩聲 but the second character is unclear.

Comment: Uploaded  pic of seal and another seal

Answer (score 1):

[image: 詩聲無]

[image: 詩聲無]

This says 「無聲詩」 (*silent poetry*), which is a phrase used to describe *paintings* - a piece of art that captures the beauty of poetry, but can't be recited.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @PipSchofield please mark the answer as solved if this answers your question.

Comment: Do you know at what time period this would have been used?

Comment: @PipSchofield unfortunately not, I can't find anything from the text itself. I'm not a connoisseur of these kinds of artifacts, maybe someone who is can give you more info.

Comment: Is it possible this seal was used on a painting by the artist or perhaps someone who appreciated a painting?

Comment: @PipSchofield yes, this would be an art seal with a poetic phrase (rather than a name or date). If used on a painting, most likely it's a secondary seal; you would find the name of the artist on another seal in the painting. You can run a translation program on [this article](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8D%B0%E7%AB%A0_(%E6%9D%B1%E4%BA%9E)#%E4%B9%A6%E6%B3%95%E8%88%87%E7%B9%AA%E7%95%AB%E4%BD%9C%E5%93%81%E4%B8%AD%E7%9A%84%E5%BA%94%E7%94%A8) for some more examples.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. Are you able to read the second seal please?

Comment: @PipSchofield I see the characters 宆見, but can't make sense of this.